# What is optimal testosterone level range for men?

Tags: testosterone, male, hormonal-imbalance

I want to know what is the optimal testosterone level range in adult males?
By stating optimal range I do not mean "normal" range. Because testosterone levels in males have significantly dropped from 800-2000 ng/Dl to 200-700 ng/Dl over the past 100 years doctors might say a level of 400 ng/Dl is normal. But it may not be normal for a man who lived a 100 years back. So I want to know what is the optimal level range? Is it 800-2000 ng/Dl? The range men had a 100 years back.

Comment: How do you define optimal?

Comment: @CareyGregory In medical doctors say "optimal" levels of vitamine D, E...etc. By optimal levels I mean levels required for optimal health